# I have a table containing row1 and row2 with same Col1 and col2 in row1 has null value,, Col2 in row2 has a value, i need replace null with value

Tags: sql-server

For ex: Table Employee has the following columns

| Name | City | Salary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sai | Bangalore | 10000 |
| Kumar | Bangalore | Null |
| Manoj | Bangalore | Null |

I need to populate 10000 in 2nd and 3rd row without using update statement.
select statement or JOINS can be used
Can some one pls provide details

Comment: Are you just looking to replace NULLs with a value? If so try the `COALESCE` function: `COALESCE(<column>,10000)`

Comment: `I need to populate 10000 in 2nd and 3rd row without using update statement` - I don't think you can update a table without using `update`.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform the following statement:

```
SELECT Name 
      ,City
      ,ISNULL(Salary, 10000) AS SaLary
FROM DataTable
```

Then import in your tool.